# Bixby natural language input - dollar amounts

Tags: bixby

I'm trying to allow users to say a dollar amount as input to a Bixby capsule.
So I made a concept of type `money.Currency`:

```
structure (Amt) {
  role-of (money.Currency)
  description (Amount to spend)
}
```

And then I gave some training examples using it:

```
[g:SomeGoal] I want to pay {[g:Amt] ($)[v:viv.money.PrefixSymbol:$](25.32)[v:viv.money.CurrencyValue]}
```

This works fine when the user enters their dollar amount in text, but it frequently fails if the user tries to speak the amount aloud to Bixby.

Example 1 (fails): The user says "I want to pay twenty-five dollars thirty-two cents." Bixby parses this as "I want to pay $25 32 cents" and populates the `Amt` field with just `$25`, leaving out the cents.

Example 2 (fails): The user says "I want to pay twenty-five thirty two." Bixby parses this as "I want to pay 2532" and populates the `Amt` field with `$2532`, again failing to fill in a value for the cents.

Example 3 (succeeds): The user says "I want to pay twenty-five point three two dollars." Bixby correctly parses this as "I want to pay $25.32" and fills in the `Amt` field with $25.32. This sounds very unnatural for English speakers though, and I do not think it will be easy to train users to speak this way.

Example 4 (sometimes succeeds):  The user says "I want to pay twenty-five dollars and thirty-two cents." Bixby sometimes parses this correctly, other times as "I want to pay $25 in 32 cents" or other similar corruptions.

Anybody have suggestions for getting Bixby to consistently understand dollar amounts in natural language? I am okay with example 2 failing since it is ambiguous, but mainly I would like examples 1 and 4 to succeed consistently. I do have one idea for a workaround (a separate cents field that's manually added to the dollars field by an action), but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible since this seems like a common case that Bixby should be able to handle on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I tried the following sentence "Pay one hundred dollars and 25 cents" multiple times and Bixby was able to transcribe it accurately every time.

But your use case (especially #1) is valid as some users tend to not use "and" to tie dollars and cents together. We will raise this internally with our team but I would suggest that you open a ticket with Bixby Developer Support so we can tie your ticket with the issue and keep you posted when its fixed.

Also, your workaround of using a second property to capture cents should work fine too. Let us know if you run into any issues.